# Force resize widget smaller than allowed

Tags: launcher, app-widgets, google-pixel

The default launcher on Google Pixel Android 12 does not allow some widgets to be resized as small as they could be. Chronos fit+ for instance is a 2x2 sized widget, so even when configured as a small 1x1 icon it still takes up extra space:

[image: home screen showing oversized widget]

This is likely an application issue, but you use to be able to resize them as small as needed. Any workarounds?

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with [the additional behavior on Android 12](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview#layout).

Answer (score 4):

This [post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/resizing-a-widget-more-than-allowed.2134548/#post-84885925) found a workaround where you change the **Display Size** option in Android settings to **Small**, resize the widget, and then change back your display size.

[image: Android display size]

[image: resize widget force smaller]